# Data-frame not being updated properly with new values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data-frame called `rawReturn` which looks like:

```
      Identifier        Entry Date  Route to current team   concatenated
0          12884    ..  01/01/2012               TRANSFER    SMITHROBERT
1          10604    ..  04/07/2013               EXTERNAL       JONESAMY
2          14445    ..  16/07/2018               EXTERNAL    EVANSSTEVEN
3           7898    ..  03/09/2010                   LOAN       HILLEMMA
:              :    ..           :                      :              :
34578      10487    ..  01/07/2012               TRANSFER     DENSMARCUS
34579      13016    ..  02/06/2014               EXTERNAL     WHITECHRIS
34580      12885    ..  09/08/2016                   LOAN     COLESDAVID
34581               ..  05/08/2014               EXTERNAL      KINGHELEN
```

I also have another data-frame called `df` which has updates that I would like to apply to the `rawReturn` data-frame. In the below example I am trying to update to the `Route to current team` column using the following `df` data-frame which looks like:

```
    Identifier  Surname First Name(s)   Route to current team   concatenated
0        10604    JONES           AMY                    LOAN       JONESAMY
1        12885     KING         HELEN                TRANSFER      KINGHELEN
```

I am trying to amend the `Route to current team` entry for each record that has a matching concatenated column value

So the resulting updated rawReturn data-frame would look like:

```
    Identifier  Entry Date      Route to current team   concatenated
0        12884  ..  01/01/2012               TRANSFER    SMITHROBERT
1        10604  ..  04/07/2013                   LOAN       JONESAMY
2        14445  ..  16/07/2018               EXTERNAL    EVANSSTEVEN
3         7898  ..  03/09/2010                   LOAN       HILLEMMA
:            :  ..           :                      :              :
34578    10487  ..  01/07/2012               TRANSFER     DENSMARCUS
34579    13016  ..  02/06/2014               EXTERNAL     WHITECHRIS
34580    12885  ..  09/08/2016                   LOAN     COLESDAVID
34581           ..  05/08/2014               TRANSFER      KINGHELEN
```

I am trying to use the following to update the rawReturn with the df data:

```
header = df.columns

for item in header[3:]:
   if item != 'concatenated':
      rawReturn.loc[rawReturn.concatenated.isin(df.concatenated),[item]] = df[item]
```

With the above I have a variable called `item` which is set to the column that I am looking to update (in this case `item` will be set to `Route to current team`) value in `rawReturn` if the `concatenated` field value is present in `df`.

The output that is currently being returned is:

```
    Identifier  Entry Date      Route to current team   concatenated
0        12884  ..  01/01/2012               TRANSFER    SMITHROBERT
1        10604  ..  04/07/2013                              JONESAMY
2        14445  ..  16/07/2018               EXTERNAL    EVANSSTEVEN
3         7898  ..  03/09/2010                   LOAN       HILLEMMA
:            :  ..           :                      :              :
34578    10487  ..  01/07/2012               TRANSFER     DENSMARCUS
34579    13016  ..  02/06/2014               EXTERNAL     WHITECHRIS
34580    12885  ..  09/08/2016                   LOAN     COLESDAVID
34581           ..  05/08/2014                             KINGHELEN
```

Where the values in this example for Amy and Helen in the `Route to current team` column (that have updates in the df data-frame) have been removed and not updated.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try `df_out = df.combine_first(rawReturn)`

Comment: Why not just `join` the 2 dataframes?

Comment: to update `Route to current team` where `rawReturn['concatenated'] == df['concatenated']` just set the index to `concatenated` then `rawReturn['Route to current team'].update(df['Route to current team'])` I am assuming that each value in `concatenated` is unique